# Medalhas Tenaz e Herói desconhecido

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução, localização, medalhas

- `Tenaz` - Perguntas aceitas com pontuação igual a zero: mais de 5 e 20% do total
- `Herói desconhecido` - Perguntas aceitas com pontuação igual a zero: mais de 10 e 25% do total

Quando o texto diz *"Perguntas aceitas"* com pontuação *"igual a zero"*, devo presumir que as perguntas devam ter pontuação igual á zero ou a resposta tenha a pontuação igual á zero?

As medalhas *contraparte* no [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges) são (com uma tradução "mais ou menos"):

- `Tenacious` - Zero score accepted answers: more than 5 and 20% of total

  > Respostas aceitas com pontuação zero: mais 5 e 20% do total
- `Unsung Hero` - Zero score accepted answers: more than 10 and 25% of total

  > Respostas aceitas com pontuação zero: mais de 10 e 25% do total

Acredito que a tradução esteja incorreta.

Comment: Este texto está errado! Hahaha.. Na descrição da medalha, o certo seria "Respostas" onde está escrito "Perguntas"

Comment: @Math então eu notei o erro pois eu frequentava muito o SOen (aquele site cruel e tirano :) ) e ganhei ambas medalhas, mas me lembro que o texto não fala nada de pergunta

Comment: Mais de um ano e meio sem ninguém perceber esse erro, pode ser um sinal que são poucos os usuários que andaram ganhando elas por aqui ;-)

Comment: @Math é que aqui o pessoal é tão generoso com votos que torna isto uma tarefa quase impossivel ... mas eu não desisto kkkkk

Comment: Já corrigi no Transifex.

Comment: @bfavaretto isto vale para o MSOPT?

Comment: Acredito que sim, mas a alteração não é imediata.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Realmente a tradução estava errada, dizia "perguntas" em vez de "respostas" – o que não me surpreende, já que foi inserida no sistema de tradução por [um esloveno](http://stackexchange.com/users/51875/m0sa) :P

Já está corrigido, deve entrar no ar em breve.

Comment: ahahahhahahah oh @bfavaretto não devias expor assim o homem :P

Comment: Obrigado :) - só não acho que seja certo adicionar a tag `status-pronto` até realmente estar pronto (status não é uma palavra em inglês ou é neologismo? - vai saber), poderia ser `status-aceito`, não?

Comment: Uns meses atrás eu conversei sobre isso com o Gabe, @GuilhermeNascimento. A orientação foi usar `status-pronto` quando o que tinha de ser feito já foi feito, dependendo apenas de um build/deploy pra entrar no ar. O `status-aceito` são pra indicar alterações que a SE se comprometeu a fazer, mas dependem de implementação ainda.

Comment: @JorgeB. Acho que você entendeu, mas caso alguém não tenha entendido, foi só uma brincadeira. O m0sa é dev do site, não foi ele quem traduziu, ele só colocou no ar.

Comment: Entendi sim :)...

Comment: Fazia tanto tempo que nem lembrava desta pergunta, fui conferir e esta ok, obrigado (faz tempo).

Comment: Nem eu lembrava, @GuilhermeNascimento :)